# Why doesn't LDP load 8 bytes into FP and LR in ARM64e?

Tags: assembly, arm64

so I have the following assembly

```
ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x40]
(lldb) memory read $sp+0x40
0x16b8f6680: 79 7a 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e  yzABCDEFGHIJKLMN
(lldb) register read $x29
      fp = 0x0000444342417a79
(lldb) register read $x30
      lr = 0x00004c4b4a494847
```

why doesn't ldp instruction load only 6 bytes into x29 and x30?

Comment: Could it be a debugger problem? What happens if you shift the registers right by 16 bits and examine the value then?

Comment: You're sure you stepped by single instructions, so no later instructions ran after this and modified those registers?  And that you single stepped *past* this instruction, so it *has* already executed?  If you set a breakpoint *on* it, it won't have executed yet.  Hmm, but that does look suspiciously like the data from memory, just truncated.

Comment: I wonder if the debugger is trying to strip out PAC bits... which wouldn't make a lot of sense for `x29`, but it does match the effect that `xpaci` would have on these values.

Comment: Just to confirm, things work normally if you do the same load into a different pair of registers?  Or similar to Jester's suggestion, if you put `eor x0, x29, x30` after the `ldp`, you should see it produce non-zero values in all bytes of `x0`.

Comment: It seems that lldb does have many features to deal with pointer tagging and authentication, which use the top 16 bits; see https://www.linaro.org/blog/lldb-15-and-the-mystery-of-the-non-address-bits/.  Although not mentioned there, it wouldn't be surprising if they also have a feature to mask off the high bits when printing a register that is likely to contain a pointer, as x30 and x29 normally would (the latter since it is usually the frame pointer). The documentation for lldb doesn't seem very complete, so one might have to refer to the source code to see how this works or to turn it off.